# How do I change a named vector to a data frame retaining the names?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, transformation, reshape

I have following data structure after executing a function:

```
      A       B       C        D        E       
      92.08   90.68   54.09    92.87    97.40    

      F       G       H        I        J       ...       
      24.52   67.24   15.63    22.33    45.10   ...
```

As a final result, I want to have the data in a simple data frame, with letters as rows and values in a column. Following worked, though I'm curious whether this is the most elegant way(?):

```
output <- data.frame(output)
output <- data.frame(rownames(output), rowSums(output))
colnames(output) <- c("Category", "Value")
output
output %>% arrange(desc(output))
```

If you have an idea to make it better, feel free to correct me.
`dplyr` solutions appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Share the `dput`. Telling us something "didn't really help" is not informative, how about you show the `str` and `class` output?

Comment: `> class(output)
[1] "numeric"`

Comment: Yeah so it's a named vector, e.g `setNames(1:26, letters)`. You can use `data.frame(Category = names(output), Value = output)`.

Comment: @Christopher Please edit your question to include the class() and str() results and change the title to reflect the actual question that was answered (How do I change a named vector to a data frame retaining the names?)

Comment: I now changed it, though I did not know what I was looking for that time.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As said by @Axeman in the comments, you have a named vector. The easiest way to transform that into a dataframe is by using the `stack`-function from base R.

Some example data:

```
output <- setNames(c(92.08,90.68,54.09,92.87,97.40), LETTERS[1:5])
```

which looks like:

> ```
> > output
>     A     B     C     D     E 
> 92.08 90.68 54.09 92.87 97.40
> ```

Transform into a dataframe with:

```
df <- stack(output)
```

which gives:

> ```
> > df
>   values ind
> 1  92.08   A
> 2  90.68   B
> 3  54.09   C
> 4  92.87   D
> 5  97.40   E
> ```

To get the columnnames and column order as specified in the question:

```
df <- setNames(stack(output)[2:1], c('Category','Value'))
```

which gives:

> ```
>   Category Value
> 1        A 92.08
> 2        B 90.68
> 3        C 54.09
> 4        D 92.87
> 5        E 97.40
> ```